# Endless loop and StackOverflow with a proxy

Tags: java, spring, proxy, cglib, dynamic-proxy

I'm trying to make the tricky thing. I have method O`bjectFactory.getObject()` which returns an `Object` that needs to implement `Serializable`. I'm trying to make a proxy of an already existing instance of `ObjectFactory`, intercept its method `getObject()` and then wrap returned object to a proxy, which implements `Serializable`.

```
@Override
public Object get(String name, ObjectFactory<?> objectFactory) {

    ...

    ObjectFactory<?> serializableObjectFactory = (ObjectFactory<?>)Proxy.newProxyInstance(CurrentClass.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{ObjectFactory.class}, new InvocationHandler() {
        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            //Here I'm getting StackOverflow exception. I guess, it just invokes itself recursively. Don't know why
            Object result = ((ObjectFactory<?>) proxy).getObject();

            //Here I make object implement Serializable
            return Mixin.create(new Class[]{Serializable.class, result.getClass()}, new Object[] {result});
        }
    });

    ...

    return super.get(name, serializableObjectFactory);
}
```

When code comes to `Object result = ((ObjectFactory<?>) proxy).getObject()` it seems just invokes itself recursively(I'm getting `StackOverflow` exception) and I have no idea why.

I have two guesses about which I can't be sure:

1. I use proxy in the wrong way. But I checked and it seems to be fine.
2. Object proxy in method `invoke()` comes as a proxy so it might invoke itself in an endless loop. I didn't find how to unwrap this proxy to a real object besides `Advise`, but it doesn't suit this proxy.

Do you have any guesses what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at this line:

```
Object result = ((ObjectFactory<?>) proxy).getObject();
```

What do you think is going to happen?

1. It invokes the proxy.
2. The proxy invokes your InvocationHandler.
3. Go back to step 1.

Maybe call the method on `objectFactory` instead?